# how do i use javascript change timezone of date without changing the time

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I have users who's local timezone can be different from a facility they are setting up event start times for. I want to take the time (say 10 am) and change the javascript date object to be 10am in the facility timezone and not the local timezones. I do know the utc offset of both local and desired timezone. I have not been able to link it all together. Here is my example.

```
var localOffset = 420;
var desiredOffset = 360;
var eventStartDate = moment(localStartDate);
eventStartDate.subtract(localOffset - desiredOffset);
```

my original time is in MDT and my desired is CDT but the start time of 10am needs to remain the same. If I can do this without using momentjs that is fine.

Comment: It looks like you have all the right pieces. What is the result of what you have?

Comment: I am unable to get the final desired date object with correct time and timezone

Comment: but what DO you get? A date with the wrong time?  Right time, wrong timezone?  An error?

Comment: if I take eventStartDate.toDate(), its exactly the same date as the one I started with.

Comment: You do not have enough information, because Time Zone != Offset

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the documentation for the `subtract` method:

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/

You're missing a unit in your call. It appears that you're using minutes, so your call should be something like:

```
eventStartDate.subtract(localOffset - desiredOffset, 'minutes');
```